# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Content loaded into ViewModel is lost after callback

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I make a callback jQuery function to fill some collections into my ViewModel with values. When I call this function again, the ViewModel loses the content populated in the first callback.

```
// ----------------------------------------------------
// ViewModel

public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedYear { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Year> Years { get; set; }

    public string SelectedCourse { get; set; }
    pulbic IEnumerable<Course> Courses { get; set; }

    public string SelectedTeacher { get; set; }
    pulbic IEnumerable<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }

    // This constructor is called when I create the ViewModel to pass for View in the "New" Controller method call.
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Years = new List<Year>() {
            new Year(1, '2013'),
            new Year(2, '2012')
        };
        Courses = new List<Course>();
        Teachers = new List<Teacher>();
    }
// ----------------------------------------------------
// View
@model Application.Models.MyViewModel
<div id="content">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedYear)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedYear, new SelectList(Model.Years, "ID", "Description"))
    @Html.Partial("Courses", Model)
    @Html.Partial("Teachers", Model)
</div>

// ----------------------------------------------------
// Courses PartialView
<div id="courses">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedCourse)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCourse, new SelectList(Model.Course, "ID", "Name))
</div>

// ----------------------------------------------------
// Teachers PartialView
<div id="teachers">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedTeacher)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedTeacher, new SelectList(Model.Teachers, "ID", "Name))
</div>

// ----------------------------------------------------
// jQuery function - called when I change the selected year.
$('#SelectedYear').change(function() {
    $.get('@Url.Action("MethodToRefreshModel", "Controller")', $('#form').serialize(), function (view) {
            $('#content').replaceWith(view);
        });
    });});

// ----------------------------------------------------
// Controller method to refresh courses
public ActionResult MethodToRefreshCourses(MyViewModel model)
{
     model.Courses = 
        (from course in context.Courses
         where course.Year.ID == Convert.ToInt64(model.SelectedYear)
         select course).ToList();

     // Returning my view with the refreshed model
     return View("New", model);
}

// Controller method to refresh teachers
public ActionResult MethodToRefreshTeachers(MyViewModel model)
{
     model.Teachers = 
        (from teacher in context.Teachers
         where teacher.Course.ID == Convert.ToInt64(model.SelectedCourse)
         select teacher).ToList();

     // Returning my view with the refreshed model
     return View("New", model);
}
```

When I call the method to refresh the courses, my page returns and display the correct data. When I selected a course to find the teachers, into my controller my model seems like "lost" the courses filled into the another method. Anyone knows what's happening and how to solve it?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

In you jquery select element change event, you are binding a function, and this function will call a function which is only return a single value (deubg the actionmethod and check which values are in model object) and after that you are replacing the whole content of the content div ( $('#content').replaceWith(view);).

you should only bind the desired control not to whole content div.

Comment: Also please check under the action the returning  View("New", model). is this "new" is that view from where you are accessing the action using jquery ?

Comment: Thanks, Abhisheks. I've tried it before. E.g.: when I update only the courses div, my ViewModel fills the new content on the page, but don't keep the values into the ViewModel. When I see the page html, the new values don't appear that. Why this?

Comment: Okay, i can not debug your code so i can just suggest you that always store your model object into viewbag property and than just use to render the view rather than using model object. It will work for you.

Comment: Thanks, Abhisheks.net. I fixed my problem loading some PartialViews with the new values and caching them if necessary. Thanks!